# system of Laguerre polynomials is orthonormal basis in space $L_2((0, \infty),e^{-t}dt)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Can you help me to prove that system of Laguerre polynomials
$$ L_n = \dfrac{e^t}{n!}\dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} (t^n e^{-t})$$ is orthonormal basis in space $L_2((0, \infty),e^{-t}dt)$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586354/orthogonality-of-laguerre-polynomials.  Please note that MathOverflow is for research-level questions only, whereas this question is a pretty standard exercise.

Comment: @NateEldredge Agreed, however the link does not totally answer the question. Here is a link treating completeness (answering the basis part of the question): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100461/on-the-completeness-of-the-generalized-laguerre-polynomials